# ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext' from 'django.utils.translation'

Tags: python, django, authentication, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I installed djangorestframework as shown below:

```
pip install djangorestframework -jwt
```

Then, I used `rest_framework_jwt.views` as shown below:

```py
from rest_framework_jwt.views import (
    obtain_jwt_token, 
    refresh_jwt_token, 
    verify_jwt_token
)
...
    path('auth-jwt/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('auth-jwt-refresh/',refresh_jwt_token),
    path('auth-jwt-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
...
```

But, I got the error below:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext' from 'django.utils.translation'

So, how can I solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading [djangorestframework-jwt](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework) will solve the error:

```
pip install djangorestframework-jwt --upgrade
```

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: This isn't the answer, the problem is that ugettext is deprecated

Answer (score 5):

from .serializers import (
File "*\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_jwt\serializers.py", line 7, in 
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _ 
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext' from 'django.utils.translation' (c:\users\dell\downloads\djangoEnvs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation_*init*_.py)

There are two ways of resolving above issues:

**Way 1: (Not recommended Approach)** 

Steps:

1. Open the last file in traceback (<path showing in your IDE>\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_jwt\serializers.py) :
2. In this file, replace ugettext with --> gettext
3. Enjoy coding!!!! :)

before replace: 
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

after replace: 
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

**Way2 : (Recommended Approach)**

Steps are:

1. Open settings.py (project folder)
2. On the top of settings.py type below imports

   ```
   import django
   from django.utils.translation import gettext
   django.utils.translation.ugettext = gettext
   ```
3. Enjoy Coding !!!!! :)