# Django app stopped working after installing django-graphql-auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, graphql, graphene-django

I was working on a Django application with GraphQL.

I installed few required libraries.

Everything seems to be working fine until I installed django-graphql-auth.

Immediately after installing that, I'm getting below error.

> /Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/bin/python manage.py runserver
> Watching for file changes with StatReloader
> Exception in thread django-main-thread:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
> fn(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
> autoreload.raise_last_exception()
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
> raise _exception[1]
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 394, in execute
> autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
> fn(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
> app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 178, in create
> mod = import_module(mod_path)
> File "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 843, in exec_module
> File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphql_jwt/**init**.py", line 1, in 
> from . import relay
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphql_jwt/relay.py", line 5, in 
> from . import mixins
> File "/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphql_jwt/mixins.py", line 1, in 
> from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
> ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext' from 'django.utils.translation' (/Users/sukumar/IntellijProjects/venvs/plotcare_be/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/**init**.py)

Process finished with exit code 0

Same issue with Python 3.11 as well.

No resolution even after uninstalling the library

Comment: Library does not seem to be maintained, which Django version did you try it with

Comment: Django version: 4.2.4

Comment: Can you format that as a code block so it can be read?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the end of the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext' from 'django.utils.translation'
```

It looks like its something to to with 'ugettext' import.

You could try this steps recomendaded [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74826436/importerror-cannot-import-name-ugettext-from-django-utils-translation)

The steps are:

1 - Open settings.py (project folder)

2 - On the top of settings.py type below imports

```
import django
from django.utils.translation import gettext
django.utils.translation.ugettext = gettext
```